# Update multiple field with MongoDB Driver 2.4.4

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to update multiple fields in a document using `MongoDb.Driver` 2.4.4.

I have searched Stackoverflow and all the potential questions that are similar are for older versions which allow chaining of `.Set()` functions. It does not appear 2.4.4 allows this.

My code currently comprises of

```
var update = MongoDB.Driver.Builders<UserLocation>.Update.Set(x => x.Loction, coordinates);
var updateResult = await this._mongo.Taps.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

I would like to update an additional field here as well and have them all update in one transaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have searched Stackoverflow and all the potential questions that are
>   similar are for older versions which allow chaining of .Set()
>   functions. It does not appear 2.4.4 allows this.

Nothing has changed here, MongoDb.Driver of 2.4.4 version still allows chaining `Set` calls.

`UpdateDefinitionBuilder<TDocument>.Set()` returns instance of `UpdateDefinition<TDocument>`. Chained `Set()` calls are done through extension method for `UpdateDefinition<TDocument>` class. This extension method is defined in `UpdateDefinitionExtensions` class from `MongoDB.Driver` namespace.

I bet you don't have using directive for `MongoDB.Driver` namespace, because in your code snippet you specify `MongoDB.Driver` namespace explicitly. That's why compiler does not know about `Set()` extension method that should be called.

To fix the problem and have chained `Set()` calls compiled, just add

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
```

at the top of your source file. Then you'll be able to chain `Set()` calls:

```
var update = Builders<UserLocation>.Update.Set(x => x.Loction, coordinates)
    .Set(x => x.SomeField1, someValue1)
    .Set(x => x.SomeField2, someValue2);
var updateResult = await this._mongo.Taps.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```